# get line in the text for each word

Tags: c, pointers, struct

The following program prints the word frequency in a file. I am trying to save for each word in the text file, which line/lines appeared and how many times in total in the whole file. It counts how many times it appeared but I can't get which lines of the txt file.

There is a problem with int lines[]. The ouput of the program gives

segmentation fault

```
    #define MAXWORDS    10000
    #define MAXSTRING   100

    /* structure holding word frequency information */

    typedef struct _word {
        char    s[MAXSTRING];   /* the word */
        int count;      /* number of times word occurs */
        int lines[1000];

    } word;


    void insert_word (word *words, int *n, char *s, int no) {
        int i;

        /* linear search for the word */
        for (i=0; i<*n; i++) if (strcmp (s, words[i].s) == 0) {

            /* found it?  increment and return. */

            words[i].count++;
            words[i].lines[words[i].count]=no;
            printf("%d", no);

            return;
        }

        /* error conditions... */

        if (strlen (s) >= MAXSTRING) {
            fprintf (stderr, "word too long!\n");
            exit (1);
        }
        if (*n >= MAXWORDS) {   
            fprintf (stderr, "too many words!\n");
            exit (1);
        }

        /* copy the word into the structure at the first available slot,
         * i.e., *n
         */

        strcpy (words[*n].s, s);

        /* this word has occured once up to now, so count = 1 */

        words[*n].count = 1;
        words[*n].lines[words[*n].count]=no;
        /* one more word */

        (*n)++;
    }


...........
int main () {
    word    words[MAXWORDS];
    char    s[1000];
    int i, n, m;

    n = 0;

FILE* file = fopen("test.txt", "r"); 


    /* read all the words in the file... */
    int no=1;
    while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), file)) {
        scanf ("%s", s);
            insert_word (words, &n, s,no);
            no=no+1;
        }
    }
        fclose(file);




    qsort((void *) words, n, sizeof (word),
        (int (*) (const void *, const void *)) wordcmp);



    if (n < 20) 
        m = n;
    else
        m = 20;



    for (i=0; i<m; i++)
        printf ("%s\t[%d] {%d} \n", words[i].s, words[i].count, words[i].lines);
}
```

Comment: Has the segmentation fault started to appear after you added the `lines` field to your struct? You are allocating 10,000 structs, each of them having 1,000 ints. That's about 40 MB, which is probably too much to allocate on the stack.

Comment: `word.lines` is an array. You can't print it with `%d`. You need to print each element.

Comment: In the file reading loop: `scanf ("%s", s);` What's this for?

Comment: @MOehm you are right. I used int *lines but I got some errors when I use it because im calling it wrong

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yes you are right. Scanf is not needed

Comment: If you really want to store all lines where a word occurs for all words, you will need a better data structure. Your rather greedy allocation tries to catch the words case, foe example "the" which occurs on every other line, but it will waste 999 ints in most cases. (Sooner or later, you will have to use dynamic memory allocation.) But storing all occurrences is probably overkill. Perhaps you could store the first and last line where a word occurs.

Comment: @MOehm i want to use dynamic memory allocation but don't know how to do that

Comment: I think you should mmap the file and add a list of pointer to the lines containing the word.
and you can store the words into a patricia trie (Radix tree).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution with dynamic memory allocation:

```
typedef struct _word {
    char *s;                /* the word */
    int count;              /* number of times word occurs */
    int *line_numbers;      // Array of line numbers
    int num_line_numbers;   // Size of the array of line numbers
} word;
// Creating a struct to hold the data. I find it's easier
typedef struct {
    word *words;      // The array of word structs
    int num_words;    // The size of the array
} word_list;

void insert_word (word_list *words, char *s, int line_number)
{
    /* linear search for the word */
    for (int i = 0; i < words->num_words; i++) {
        if (strcmp (s, words->words[i].s) == 0) {
            /* found it?  increment and return. */
            words->words[i].count++;

            // See if it already appeared in this line
            if (words->words[i].line_numbers[words->words[i].num_line_numbers - 1] == line_number) {
                return;
            }

            // New line number. Increase the line number array by one
            int *tmp = realloc(words->words[i].line_numbers, sizeof(int) * (words->words[i].num_line_numbers + 1));
            if (NULL == tmp) exit(0);
            words->words[i].line_numbers = tmp;
            // Add the line number to the array
            words->words[i].line_numbers[words->words[i].num_line_numbers] = line_number;
            words->words[i].num_line_numbers += 1;
            return;
        }
    }

    /* error conditions... */
    ....

    // Increase the size of the word array by one.
    word *tmp = realloc(words->words, sizeof(word) * (words->num_words + 1));
    if (tmp == NULL) exit(0);
    words->words = tmp;    

    /* copy the word into the structure at the first available slot,
     * i.e., *n
     */
    words->words[words->num_words].s = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    strcpy(words->words[words->num_words].s, s);

    /* this word has occurred once up to now, so count = 1 */

    words->words[words->num_words].count = 1;
    words->words[words->num_words].line_numbers = malloc(sizeof(int));
    words->words[words->num_words].line_numbers[0] = line_number;
    words->words[words->num_words].num_line_numbers = 1;
    words->num_words += 1;
}

bool remove_word(word_list *words, const char *word_to_delete)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < words->num_words; i++) {
        if (0 == strcmp(words->words[i].s, word_to_delete)) {
            // TODO: handle special case where there is only 1 word in list

            // Calc number of words after found word
            int number_of_words_to_right = words->num_words - i - 1;
            // Free mem
            free(words->words[i].s);
            free(words->words[i].line_numbers);
            // Copy remaining words
            memcpy(&words->words[i], &words->words[i + 1], sizeof(word) * number_of_words_to_right);
            // Resize the array (technically not required)
            word *tmp = realloc(words->words, sizeof(word) * --words->num_words);
            if (NULL == tmp) exit(0);
            words->words = tmp;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And in `main()`

```
    word_list *words = malloc(sizeof(word_list));
    if (NULL == words) exit(0);
    memset(words, 0, sizeof(word_list));

    ....

    /* read all the words in the file... */
    char s[1000];
    int line_number = 1;
    while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), file)) {
        char *word = strtok(s, " ");
        while (word != NULL) {
            size_t len = strlen(word);
            if (len > 0 && word[len - 1] == '\n') word[--len] = 0;
            insert_word(words, word, line_number);
            word = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        line_number += 1;
    }
    fclose(file);

    for (int i = 0; i < words->num_words; i++) {
        printf("%s\t\t[%d] {", words->words[i].s, words->words[i].count);
        for (int j = 0; j < words->words[i].num_line_numbers; j++) {
            if (j != 0) printf(",");
            printf("%d", words->words[i].line_numbers[j]);
        }
        printf("}\n");
    }

    // It's good practice to always free mem. It's super not important
    // in this app since the OS will do it when you exit
    for (int i = 0; i < words->num_words; i++) {
        free(words->words[i].s);
        free(words->words[i].line_numbers);
    }
    free(words->words);
    free(words);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time to answer.I really appreciate! It looks more powerful. When you say error handling..Im not sure if I know how. Do I keep the other parts in main?

Comment: It's up to you on how to handle the error. If `malloc` fails, you've got problems and should probably terminate the program. Also, I've only included parts I changed. The other parts seem ok.

Comment: Ok thank you. I terminate the program with exit(0)? How do I print each word in the struct in a new line and next to it how many times it occured, and the lines? it seems the for I had does not works

Comment: The `// handle error` parts are just placeholders for your error handling code. You can replace with something like `exit(0);`. I have updated code.

Comment: Thank you. I will see what else I can do there. How can I remove nodes from the structure? I mean to have an option (y/n) for user to remove "stop words " (after it add the words) that a specific filename "stop.txt" contains. It contains lets say a string in each line which have to remove from the structure.

Comment: Since the data is an array, you would have to find the word, move everything after it to the left by one. Then call `realloc(words->words, sizeof(word) * (words->num_words - 1));`. Also, decrease `words->num_words` by one.

Comment: I tried but i think im doing wrongs `void remove_word (word_list *words, char *str)
{
    /* linear search for the word */
    for (int i = 0; i < words->num_words; i++) {
        if (strcmp (str, words->words[i].s) == 0) {
            word *tmp=words->words[words->num_words].s
            free(words->words[i].s)

             *tmp = realloc(words->words, sizeof(word) * (words->num_words - 1));
            if (tmp == NULL) exit(0);
            words->words = tmp;    
           words->num_words = words->num_words -1;
            return;
        
        }
    }
    return;
}`